# non printable characters in a string - php

Tags: php, character-encoding

I am debugging a Drupal module (this module,webform_import,imports CSV data into the database) and getting some non-printable character causing error in the module. Here is my debugging code

```
if($v == 'semester'){
    dpm('found ' . $v);
}
else
{
    dpm('not found ' . $v);
    dpm(str_split($v));
}
dpm($v);
```

The variable $v is passed through following function

```
function _webform_import_csvfieldtrim($value) {
  $value = trim($value);
  // Strip off the beginning and ending quotes if necessary.
  $value = preg_replace('/^".*"$/', '', $value);
  // Remove control characters. Some editors add invalid EOL chars.
  // fgetcsv does not handle unicode characters therefore we replace them
  // manually. See http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31632.
  $value = str_replace('\x00..\x1F\xfe\xff', '', $value);
  //$value = str_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $value);

  return $value;
}
```

This is the output of my debugging
[image: output of debugging code]

According to the output, $v prints 'semester' but is not equal to string 'semester' and when converted into an array has 11 characters instead of 8. Please let me know if something is wrong with the _webform_import_csvfieldtrim function. Also, I have converted the CSV file's encoding to UTF-8.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The first 3 invisible characters are BOM. I changed the encoding to 'UTF-8 without BOM' and the module worked.